# There are two table having same type of records in that finding the unused record from table2 in table1

Tags: mysql

Table1: Account & Table2: AccountDtl.

Account table having column as Account_Num.

AccountDtl table having column as Account_value.

Both Account_Num and Account_value having same type of values.

For Example:

```
Account_num
10001
10002
10003
10004

Account_value
10001 
10002
10003
10004
10005
10006
10007
```

Now i have to get (10005, 10006 ,10007) record in Account_value (column).
How to write sql query?

I had tried in this way.But didn't get my expected output.

Select k.Account_value from AccountDtl k left outer join Account a on k.Account_value = a.Account_num;

Comment: show example expected output

Comment: What happens to `10005` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *think* what you want here is the difference between the values in `AccountDtl` and those in `Account`.  One way of doing this is to `LEFT JOIN` the former table against the latter and then use `NULL` to identify records you want to retain.  Something like this:

```
SELECT Account_value
FROM AccountDtl a1
LEFT JOIN Account a2
    ON a1.Account_value = a2.Account_num
WHERE a2.Account_num IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
select ad.Account_value 
from AccountDtl ad 
left join Account ac 
on (ad.Account_Value = ac.Account_Num) 
where ac.Account_num is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **[`NOT EXISTS`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html)**

**Query**

```
SELECT `Account_value` FROM `AccountDtl` t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 FROM `Account` t2
    WHERE t1.`Account_value` = t2.`Account_num`
);
```